# Drawer without appbar Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a Drawer inside of a Container, without using an appbar. Actually I need to do this screen, but only need help with that rounded shape that is in the background.

Thanks!

[this is the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfPCb.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, create a Globalkey for Scaffold.
Like this..

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

And give that key to Scaffold

```
Scaffold (
  key: _scaffoldKey,
  child: Container(),
)
```

And when you want to open the Drawer..

```
onTap(): _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
onTap: () {Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(); },
```

Comment: Add some explanation of your code would be preferred.